# jQuery AJAX Cannot Find Local File in WordPress Installation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm having trouble with a WordPress plugin I've been working on. A JS file is loaded as a resource with each page/post opened, which in turn has a request to load the contents of an HTML file.

Being that the page/post directories change frequently, I'm having a difficult time making the jQuery dynamically pin down the location of the file (even though it's in the same location as the rest of the plugin resources).

An example:

```
  jQuery('body').append('<section id="asub00LOAD"></section>');

var url = jQuery(location).attr('hostname');
var dir = url + '/wp-content/plugins/adsenseunblock/html/adunblock.html #asub00AJAX';

jQuery('#asub00LOAD').load(dir);
```

That was placing the whole URL path to the file after the local install ("root.com/CHEETOS/" in this case):
[image]

After which, I did this, which works fine for the root directory only:

```
  jQuery('body').append('<section id="asub00LOAD"></section>');

var dir = 'wp-content/plugins/adsenseunblock/html/adunblock.html #asub00AJAX';

jQuery('#asub00LOAD').load(dir);
```

After you venture to another page, obviously the directory location is wrong again.

I tried to place some PHP into my JS file before so I could take advantage of the $plugins_url feature, but that became very convoluted and it's hard to track any errors without a PHP console to work from...

I hope someone here will have a solution for me!

Answer (score 0):

The first example probably fails because there's no `http://` (or `//`)

Use `var url = "//"  + location.hostname;`

The second example should work everywhere if you use a root-relative path:

`var dir = '/wp-content/plugins/adsenseunblock/html/adunblock.html #asub00AJAX';`

Comment: The second one didn't work because the JS seems to base its location off wherever it's executed - so when I venture out of the root directory to "mySite.com/category/post-name-123/" then it's going to tack the rest of the directory on the end of that.

Comment: but i'll try your first one now and see if that works. I've been attempting to load it in with PHP now by appending the php to the body:

<?php $divs = plugins_url( 'html/HTMLFILE.html', __FILE__ ); include_once('$divs'); ?>

Comment: Yeah I just tried your first suggestion and it's pretty much exactly the same thing as I had done with the jQuery there - I want this to function regardless of the directory / install location, so far the only way to get the exact location seems to be through PHP

Comment: I'd love it if I could find a JS solution though - especially since my PHP skills are awful and I can't find a way to do it with that either.

Comment: Hmm strange... Check your network tab to see what address jquery actually requests. I'd guess it's wordpress redirecting to a wrong location.